# Automating testing calling other scripts

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have a list of selenium scripts and I want to test them to see if they work correctly I.e 1.py, 2.py, 3.py, 4.py, 5.py in folder C:\Selenium scripts.

Obviously, I’d rather not have to sit there and watch as I’m fairly certain they work but I want to be sure.  How do I go about automating my testing?

I’m aware of frameworks though a simpler approach I believe would be to call each script to another In Python.  Though if any stopped because of an error, this would not work.  I suppose you could create a try and except block (not sure if this is good practise but it would work maybe).

Ideally I would run them all at once, but multithreading is not supported in Selenium lest you create problems.

How do I effectively run automated tests?

You could use cxfreeze and call each script, but it’s not really known when they finish or if they finish and create errors then the other jobs will not run.

Calling another script e.g:

1_module.py

```
def main():
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    import os
    import sys
    import os
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path)
    driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com")
    import 2.2_module
        2.2_module.do_something_in_2()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

2_module.py

```
import selenium
print('testing...actions..')
```

Comment: Have you used Unit tests for this? could you show us an example of one of your files to see what youre doing?

Comment: @Goralight I'm still very new to python.  I  have shown an example which doesn't work.  Maybe this method fixing it or using multithreading framework is way to go.

Comment: unittest module + subprocess module

Answer (score 0):

You just basically need a *test runner with automatic test discovery*. Even though the standard built-in `unittest` module has these capabilities, I'd recommend to take a look at [`pytest` test runner](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/).

Comment: @geeg if you have tests that match the [pytest discovery logic](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/pythoncollection.html), it would auto-discover them automatically and run.